# Show that two field extensions are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I am new to this and I was hoping to get some help so that I can better understand field extensions.

> Given $\omega=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$, I want to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega,\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far? What are the definitions (that you know) of these two field extensions? We'll have a more difficult time giving you a satisfactory answer without such information.

Comment: Hint: Show that one is contained in the other and that they have the same degree over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Sorry. I can see that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\sqrt[3]{2})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\omega,\sqrt[3]{2})$ since it is the smallest extension field containing $\omega+\sqrt[3]{2}$. I'm having trouble with the other inclusion though.

Comment: @user291189 Show that they have the same degree over $\mathbb{Q}$.  This, together with one inclusion, implies that they are equal.

Comment: @Slade thank you that makes sense. Can someone help me show that they have the same degree over $\mathbb{Q}$? I need to show that the minimum polynomials have the same degree, right?

Comment: @user291189 The minimum polynomials of what and what?

Comment: @Slade of $\omega+\sqrt[3]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and... I guess I'm not so sure how to find the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega,\sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @user291189 By considering sub-extensions, show that it is divisible by both $2$ and $3$.

Comment: @Slade, I have been trying to find the minimum polynomial of $\omega+\sqrt[3]{2}$, and I just used Wolfram Alpha to see that the minimum polynomial has degree 6. Without using a computer, I don't have anything that would have let me find this polynomial, and I don't have a way to verify that this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is there any other way to deduce that the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is 6?

Comment: Here are two ways to compute the minimal polynomial of $\omega + \sqrt[3]{2}$.  1) Write $\alpha = \omega + \sqrt[3]{2}$.  Then $2 = \sqrt[3]{2}^3 = (\alpha - \omega)^3$.  Multiply this out, move terms with $\omega$ to the other side, and then square both sides.  2) The roots of the minimal polynomial will be exactly the Galois conjugates of $\omega + \sqrt[3]{2}$.  These are $\omega + \omega^k \sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\omega^2 + \omega^k \sqrt[3]{2}$ for $k = 0, 1, 2$.  Multiply out the product of $x - \rho$ for roots $\rho$ just listed and you'll have the min poly.

Comment: After finding a degree $6$ rational polynomial $p$ such that $p(\omega + \sqrt[3]{2})=0$ (both of SpamIAm's methods, particularly the first one, work by hand), it is important to check that this polynomial is irreducible.  With no computer assistance, probably the easiest approach is to observe that $p(x)\equiv x^6\pmod{3}$, and so the non-leading terms of each factor must be divisible by 3.  Then we can divide into two cases (three cubics or two quadratics) and use a little brute force.  This is basically mimicking the proof of Eisenstein, which we cannot use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

Since $\mathbb{Q}(\omega + \sqrt[3]{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2})$, and the latter has degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, it suffices to show that the minimal polynomial of $t=\omega + \sqrt[3]{2}$ has degree $6$.

---

We can find a polynomial equation for $t$ as follows:
$$2 = (t-\omega)^3 = t^3 - 3\omega t^2 + 3\omega^2 t - \omega^3$$
$$= t^3 - 3\omega t^2 + 3(-\omega - 1)t - 1$$
$$ = (t^3 - 3t - 1) + (-3t^2 - 3t)\omega$$

and so $\omega = (t^3 - 3t - 3)/(3t^2 + 3t)$.  Plugging in to $\omega^2 + \omega + 1=0$ and clearing denominators gives us $t^6 + 3t^5 + 6t^4 + 3t^3 + 9t + 9 = 0$.

---

The last step is to show that $p(X) = X^6 + 3X^5 + 6X^4 + 3X^3 + 9X + 9$ is irreducible.  Suppose otherwise.

First, note that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega,t) = \mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2})$.  It follows that $t$ cannot have degree $2$, so it must have degree $3$.  It follows that $p(X)$ has a cubic factor.

It is easy to check that $p$ has no linear factor, and so $p(X)=q(X)r(X)$ is the product of two cubics.

Clearly, $p(X)\equiv X^6\pmod{3}$.  Since $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, we have $q(X),r(X)\equiv X^3\pmod{3}$.

By considering the coefficient of $X^3$ in $p(X)$, modulo $9$, we find that the constant terms of $q$ and $r$ are both $-3$.

Write $q(X) = X^3 + aX^2 + bX - 3$.  Looking at the $X^5$ and $X$ coefficients of $p(X)$, we find that $r(X) = X^3 + (3-a)X^2 + (-3-b)X - 3$.

From this, we can calculate the $X^2$ coefficient of $p(X)$ to be $b(-3-b)-9=0$, so $b^2 + 3b + 9 = 0$, which has no solutions in integers.

---

Here is another method that also works by hand, and is much shorter, though thinking of it probably requires a computer:

Note that $X^2 + 2$ divides $p(X)\pmod{5}$.  Since $p(X)$ has no root modulo $5$, $p(X)$ cannot be the product of two cubic factors.